# Passing credentials to Big Query from JSON key file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

I'm connecting to Big Query from a Java client using [this example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file) from the public documentation.

There's an error message:

> "The method setCredentials(Credentials) from the type 
>   ServiceOptions.Builder  refers to the missing type Credentials"

What am I missing?

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Dataset;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.DatasetInfo;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldValueList;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryResponse;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableResult;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public void connectBQ() {

  GoogleCredentials credentials1;
  File credentialsPath = new File("service_account.json");  // TODO: update to your key path.
  try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
    credentials1 = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
  }

  // Instantiate a client.
  BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials1).build().getService();
  BigQuery bigquery1= BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials1).setProjectId("1234").build().getService();

  // Use the client.
  System.out.println("Datasets:");
  for (Dataset dataset : bigquery.listDatasets().iterateAll()) {
    System.out.printf("%s%n", dataset.getDatasetId().getDataset());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issues are usually thrown when a client object tries to authenticate to your GCP account services by using invalid GCP credentials. Based on this, it is probable that the service account file path that you are using to initialize your credentialsPath variable are invalid, making the setCredentials method fail when trying to connect to the service.

> File credentialsPath = new File("service_account.json");  // TODO: update to your key path.

I suggest you to verify your are using the correct file path of your JSON credential key file as well as take a look to the [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) guideline that explains the process required to create your [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account), [Service account key (JSON file)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) and [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#bigquery_roles) roles in case you haven't create them yet.  In this way, you will be able to use them to initialize your credentialsPath variable and implement the Google's example without problem.